# XSL XPath select mixed text and node in order within for-each loop?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to use XSL to transform an XML document into an HTML page. I am 95% of the way there, but I am running into problems with nodes that contain both text and other nodes which must be displayed in order.

XML:

```xml
<chapter title="Chapter 1" reqlen="2500">
    <section title="The Quick Brown Fox">
        <subsection title="null">
            <keywords>foo,bar</keywords>
            <body>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum <b>dolor sit amet</b>, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
                    <int>foo/bar/qux</int>
                    Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
                    <ext>http://google.com/</ext>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Foo bar <b>doqux amet</b>, foo adipiscing elit. 
        Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
                    <int>foo/bar/qux</int>
                    Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
                    <ext>http://google.com/</ext>
                </p>
            </body>
            <note>Lorem ipsum</note>
        </subsection>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

XSL:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" id="stylesheet" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
    <xsl:template match="/chapter">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </title>
                <style type="text/css">body {
            padding: 50px 10%;
          }</style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="section">
                    <xsl:if test="@title!='null'">
                        <h2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                        </h2>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="subsection">
                        <xsl:if test="@title!='null'">
                            <h3>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                            </h3>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:for-each select="body/p">
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                            </p>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in the following HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Chapter 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            padding: 50px 10%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <h2>The Quick Brown Fox</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
            foo/bar/qux
            Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
            http://google.com/
        </p>
        <p>
            Foo bar doqux amet, foo adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
            foo/bar/qux
            Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
            http://google.com/
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, I am trying to transform certain tags within the `<p></p>` nodes.

Inside of `<p>` nodes, there can be a mixture of plain text and the nodes `<b></b>`, `<i></i>`, `<int></int>`, `<ext></ext>`, and `<cvc></cvc>`. There will never be nesting beyond this level, i.e. a `<b></b>` will only ever contain text.

This is my desired HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Chapter 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            padding: 50px 10%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <h2>The Quick Brown Fox</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
            <a href="/foo/bar/qux">foo/bar/qux</a>
            Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
            <a href="http://google.com/">http://google.com/</a>
        </p>
        <p>Foo bar <strong>doqux amet</strong>, foo adipiscing elit. 
            Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
            <a href="/foo/bar/qux">foo/bar/qux</a>
            Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
            <a href="http://google.com/">http://google.com/</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried different XPath functions, `for-each` loops, and mixtures of the two, but I can't figure out how to get the output I want. The closest I've gotten is with this XSL:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" id="stylesheet" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
    <xsl:template match="/chapter">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </title>
                <style type="text/css">body {
            padding: 50px 10%;
          }</style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="section">
                    <xsl:if test="@title!='null'">
                        <h2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                        </h2>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="subsection">
                        <xsl:if test="@title!='null'">
                            <h3>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                            </h3>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:for-each select="body/p">
                            <p>
                                <xsl:for-each select="text()">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:for-each select="b">
                                    <strong>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                                    </strong>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:for-each select="int">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                                    </a>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:for-each select="ext">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                                    </a>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </p>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the HTML output is out of order:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Chapter 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            padding: 50px 10%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
        <h2>The Quick Brown Fox</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum , consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
            Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
            <strong>dolor sit amet</strong><a href="#">foo/bar/qux</a><a href="#">http://google.com/</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            Foo bar , foo adipiscing elit.
            Maecenas sed pretium nunc.
            Proin tincidunt sapien dolor, posuere varius dui efficitur ac.
            <strong>doqux amet</strong><a href="#">foo/bar/qux</a><a href="#">http://google.com/</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use template rules. Recursive processing of the XML tree using template rules is the natural way to use XSLT, and is especially important for handling mixed content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
  <xsl:template match="/chapter">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
          body {
          padding: 50px 10%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
        </h1>
        <xsl:for-each select="section">
          <xsl:if test="@title!='null'">
            <h2>
              <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
            </h2>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:for-each select="subsection">
            <xsl:if test="@title!='null'">
              <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
              </h3>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:for-each select="body/p">
              <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="b">
    <strong>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </strong>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="int">
    <a href="#">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ext">
    <a href="#">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```